# Sppull library: download files returning empty array for sharepoint files

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Code:

```
const context = {
    siteUrl: 'https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com',
  creds: {
    username: "<username>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com",
    password: "***",
    online: true
  }
};

const options2 = {
    spRootFolder: "Shared%20Documents/docverify",
    dlRootFolder: "./docverify"
  };

SPPull.download(context, options2)
  .then((downloadResults) => {
    console.log("Files are downloaded", downloadResults);
    console.log("For more, please check the results", JSON.stringify(downloadResults));
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Core error has happened", err);
  });
```

Output:

```
Files are downloaded []
For more please check the results []
```

Attached screenshot of the file in sharepoint
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crZEh.jpg)

Files to be downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Please change "%20" for a "\ "

Your code:

```
spRootFolder: "Shared%20Documents/docverify"
```

My code:

```
spRootFolder: "Shared\ Documents/docverify"
```

It functions for me.